# Is it ok to replace a torsion coil spring without a middle bracket bearing?

Tags: doors, garage, load-bearing, home-automation, mount

Its a single door with a 1020 overhead door opener.  It seems it was installed with the fixed end  mounted to the side rail. The adjustable tensioner bolt assembly with the square bolts are towards the middle.

Comment: I'm just going to point you here. Read through the comments. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/273739/18078 The advisability of DIY torsion spring adjustments (or replacements, which require adjustments) is debatable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  "its a single door..."  means an 8 ft' door for a single car garage, there is not a need for a center bracket bearing.

Many will tell you this is a dangerous job, that should be left to a professional.  I will not disagree.  However I have changed springs on a few doors.  It can be done with the same type of diligence and care used when doing electrical work.

The best advice if you do decide to DIY this, is the spring does not need to be wound as tight as you think.

Good luck.

Comment: When installing the spring how dose one know where along the axle to locate the end fitting that is secured to the axle? I imagine one wants to minimize the rubbing of the coils against each other as the door is raised or lowered. This suggests having the spring stretched out, but there must be a limit to this. For a given spring how does one determine the distance between the end fittings?

Comment: Coils rubbing is not an issue.  With the door closed the spring/s are manually tensioned, (This is the dangerous part) .  Once this is achieved the spring is tightened to the axle where it sits.  Most DIYers make the spring too tight, always assuming it will not lift the door.

Comment: You read the instructions, @JimStewart. When I put up my torsion spring for my new garage door, the instructions told me where on the axle the center mount (it's a 2-car door) and the end mounts needed to go. It also told me how many turns to _start_ with, then make adjustments from there.